# How to use mysql_escape_string() in Yii framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, sql-injection

As we all know, we cannot use raw MySQL queries in frameworks such as Yii. I want to use `mysql_escape_string` in my project which runs in Yii framework to get away from SQL injection in user input.

I am aware that `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and that I have a PDO alternative. What is the alternative in Yii framework and also the PDO way of mysql_escape_string()?

Comment: Have you tried reading the Yii documentation for working with databases? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Comment: you don't escape in PDO, except in very limited circumstances. you use a prepared statement with placeholders. No escaping required

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alternative to `mysql_escape_string` in PDO is using prepared statements. In Yii for example:

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('username, password')
    ->from('tbl_user')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$_GET['userId']))
    ->queryRow();
```

(From the Yii reference documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand)

You are secured you against SQL injection when you pass parameters through placeholders in a prepared statement.

Comment: But in some cases that does not work: Like in MATCH... AGAINST

Comment: @Roel it's not true.  prepared statements work with MATCH... AGAINST

Answer (score 5):

It is best to use **prepared statements** for automatic parameter escaping. However, this method of CDbConnection should also do the trick:

```
Yii::app()->db->quoteValue($your_value);
```

In essence this quotes a string value for use in a query, it is a wrapper of `PDO::quote()`.

Read more [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#quoteValue-detail).

Answer (score 3):

Escaping the query parameters using the prepared queries '?' placeholders has its drawbacks (the escaped parameter is moved away from the body of the query, thus making some queries harder to work with; there might be an additional roundtrip to the database which isn't always justified; if the query is essentially dynamic then preparing lots of them might actually take server resources).

Yii has the [quoteValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#quoteValue-detail) method which can be used to escape the query parameters outside of the prepared query form.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHTMlPurifier:

```
// Example
$p = new CHtmlPurifier();

$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('username, password')
    ->from('tbl_user')
    ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$p->purify($_GET['userId']);))
    ->queryRow();
```

It is possible add malicious code in get parameters.

Comment: What vulnerability does the code have if you fail to call `purify`?

Comment: @Joni: Security flaws: XSS, Cookies Theft, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape parameters if using `ActiveRecords`.

However, if you want to use that `mysql_escape_string` function you can try with `mysqli_escape_string()`

I've used this with `Yii` when executing high complexity queries that would have had performance issues if working with models and I needed to execute SQL queries directly to the DB.

For doing this, you can use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll()` (or any other similar function).