# mysqli_real_escape_string within Yii 2 using DAO or something else?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and about to starting working with databases for the first time within it and was wondering if `Yii 2` had something else you should use to prepare data for the database such as the standard `mysqli_real_escape_string` function or should I just use that?

I'm not using prepared statements, I'm accessing the database via their [database access objects](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html) and wondering how I go about escaping the data I pass to it?

I found the [quoteValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#quoteValue%28%29-detail) method but it's included within what Yii calls `Connection represents a connection to a database via PDO.` so I wasn't sure if it was the right method to use?

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14897638/1588163

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use mysql\_escape\_string() in Yii framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897547/how-to-use-mysql-escape-string-in-yii-framework)

Comment: @clapas That question was for Yii 1.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you said, you should use `quoteValue`.

If your dao component name is `db`, then you should simply try :

```
$quoteValue = \Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yii2 uses param binding so pass any user input as a param and not directly into the SQL via concatenation.

```
$query->where('status=:status', [':status' => $status]);
//or
$query->where('status=:status');
$query->addParams([':status' => $status]);
//or
$query->where(['status' => 10]);
```

Ref http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where

Comment: I don't want to do it like that, I want to do it normally as per my link. For example: `$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=1');`

Comment: Then you should use prepared statements and placeholders, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#using-prepared-statements

Comment: I don't want to do that either; I simply want to pass a properly escaped value into a query that can be used within the `createCommand` method.

Comment: Can't help you then if you don't want to make use of the secure features the framework provides.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with escaping the data yourself; not everyone wants to go through the hassle of writing more code than you need to when you can just write out the query itself.

Comment: Why use the dao component in Yii2 anyway? you can probably write directly to the socket. Get really hard core.